# ajax stop send data if click on other user

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**This is the HTML CODE:**

```
<?php
    foreach ($doctors as $value) {  
?> 
    <div style="overflow: hidden !important; padding: 0 10px; font-weight: bolder;">
        <div style="padding: 4px;border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;overflow: hidden;cursor: pointer;" class='sidebar-members'  data-user='{{Encryption::decrypt($value->first_name)." ".Encryption::decrypt($value->last_name)}}' >
            <div class="col-md-4 "> 
                <img  height="34" src="assets/images/{{$value->images}}" alt="{{Encryption::decrypt($value->first_name)." ".Encryption::decrypt($value->last_name)}}">
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-7"> 
               <span >{{Encryption::decrypt($value->first_name)." ".Encryption::decrypt($value->last_name)}}</span>
               <input type="hidden" name="user_name" id="user_name" value="{{$value->id}}">
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-1"></div> 
        </div>
    </div> 
<?php
    }
?>
</div>
```

java script

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    pending_chat_reload();
    function pending_chat_reload(){

        $("body").on('click','.sidebar-members',function(){

            var username = $(this).attr("data-user");
            if(username!=username){
                clearTimeout(username);
                var username1 = $(this).attr("data-user");
            } 
            setInterval(function() { vpb_chat_display(username1); }, 1000);
            //setTimeout(vpb_chat_display(username), 1000);
        });

    }
    //setTimeout(vpb_chat_display(username), 1000);
    function vpb_chat_display(username){
        console.log(username);
    }
```

**The Problem that I facing in my HTML is:**

The ajax stop send data if click on other user,

If anyone know how to solve this, please suggestion me a solution, Thank you.

ps. Is my Code having problem? or the method i using is wrong?

Comment: Can you please elaborate to your question or be specific.

Comment: Hi, could you please provide more information with your question? At the current state, it's unclear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: please take some time to format your code - this is virtually illegible. And also please explain your question further

Comment: when i click on username getting from foreach loop i get its value in javascript and my jquery start fetching its data continously i want that i click on other user the jquery stop for first user and start running for another user on which i click to reload the chat

Comment: Can you please provide the complete code?

Comment: the problem is wriiten in above

Comment: if anyone have idea plz answer it

Comment: It kind of looks like you are mixing PHP and JS together. PHP runs on the server while JS runs on the browser. Check if you are refreshing the JS when somethings changes on page.

Comment: `if(username!=username)` - how often do you expect that variable to not be equal to itself? If you have quantum computing technology already, I’m impressed - but otherwise this is of course just a nonsense statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

   usernametemp = "";
    pending_chat_reload();
    function pending_chat_reload(){

        $("body").on('click','.sidebar-members',function(){

            var username = $(this).attr("data-user");
            if(username!=usernametemp){
                clearTimeout(username);
                var usernametemp = $(this).attr("data-user");
            } 
            setInterval(function() { vpb_chat_display(usernametemp); }, 1000);
            //setTimeout(vpb_chat_display(username), 1000);
        });

    }
    //setTimeout(vpb_chat_display(username), 1000);
    function vpb_chat_display(username){
        console.log(username);
    }
```

Comment: if(username!=usernametemp){
                clearTimeout(username);
                var usernametemp = $(this).attr("data-user");
            } This condition never be true